# Is there intramolecular H-bonding in 2-hydroxybenzonitrile?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, hydrogen-bond, phenols

Is there an intramolecular hydrogen bonding in 2-hydroxybenzonitrile? If so, then the $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ order should be meta > ortho > para but the actual order is meta > para > ortho.

I think since the $\ce{-CN}$ group is linear in shape hence the distance between $\ce{-OH}$ group and $\ce{-CN}$ is large so there should not be any hydrogen bonding between them.

[image]

Comment: You think right.